# grabbing form with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery 3.2.1 to grab input forms. the problem is that I don't get anything out, empty object or empty string. I tried with serialize, serialize array, code from SO to get the fields and transform to json, nothing did work.

I am sure that I wrote correctly the form id because the subscription of the function is successful.

here are part of the html:

```
<form role="form" id="organisationform">
    <div class="row col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            <label for="name" class="h4">Nom Organisation</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomOrg" placeholder="Nom de l'organisation" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            <label for="lastname" class="h4">Identificateur </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idOrg" placeholder="Entrer IDentificateur" required>
        </div>
    </div>
...
</form>
```

and here is the js code:

```
onSubmit('form#organisationform', function() {
    send('http://localhost:8080/organisation/ajouter', 'form#organisationform');
});
```

in an other file:

```
function grabForm(formId) {
var data = {};
 $(this).serializeArray().map(function(x){data[x.name] = x.value;}); 
return data;
}

function send(url, formId) {

var data = grabForm(formId);

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    ...
});
}

function onSubmit(idform, fn) {
$(idform).submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
fn();
});
}
```

the problem is on the grab thing function it's returns an empty object, but before this form it was serialize function.

in an other test, I just Copy-Paste code from SO:

```
    $('#organisationform').submit(function () {
  var $inputs = $('#organisationform :input');

// not sure if you wanted this, but I thought I'd add it.
// get an associative array of just the values.
var values = {};
$inputs.each(function() {
    values[this.name] = $(this).val();
});

 alert(values);
  //Do stuff with view object here (e.g. JSON.stringify?)
});
```

same problem.

SO how can I fix this? or how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are wrapping the jQuery functions in a load of your own functions which don't actually seem to add any value, but are overcomplicating things, in particular making the scope uncertain and making the flow of control hard to follow.

This should be sufficient to submit the form via ajax:

```
$("form#organisationform").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/organisation/ajouter",
    data: $(this).serialize(), //serialise the form, which due to the scope can be fetched via 'this',
    method: "POST", //assuming it's a POST, but set it to whatever is right for your server
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); //receive any response from the server
    },
    error: function(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown + " " + textStatus); //log any HTTP errors encountered
    }
    //...etc
  });
});
```

You may need to tweak things depending on what exactly the server expects to receive.

Comment: you'll have to give a bit more detail than that. Where did it fail? Do you get any errors in your browser console? if so, what are they? If we're going to fix it we'll need proper details of the issue. Just saying "didn't work" doesn't allow us to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I think that jquery use 'name' attributes to grab inputs because when I changed the input  to use 'name' instead of 'id' I got a result. SO error is in html

Comment: well spotted, I hadn't noticed that. You're right, form controls without a "name" attribute are never submitted to the server. (You can have "name" and "id" attributes at the same time on an element, they have different purposes).

Answer (score 0):

ouch! I changed the input with name attributes instead of id, now it can grab things!